# Imported PDF figure special character problem

Tags: pdf, unicode

I am importing a PDF figure using `\includegraphics`. This PDF figure contains a greek sigma and a greek Delta capital. In my PDF output, the sigma is output correctly, however instead of a capital delta, an ø is shown. This is both the case when using `pdflatex` and `xetex`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you upload a minimal version of that pdf exhibiting the problem somewhere? Also what's your environment (version of TeX, operating system...)?

Comment: How can I upload a file here?